# is this mold or something else?

Tags: paint, mold

Is this (the red and the round brown rusted looking thing) mold?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you zoom in, this looks like a Phillips head screw. The discoloration around the head of the screw likely comes from rusting of the screw.

Comment: Or rusting of the rear side panel of the Volkswagen mini-bus.

Comment: I agree, the round mark is a popped wallboard screw that is now rusting. Drive it back in, spackle over it, and hit it with some touch-up paint. The other marks, lower on the wall, appear to be years worth of dirty stains caused by splashes, like if someone was carelessly mopping near that wall.

Answer (score 0):

It would really really help if you posted with a lot more context and with a much clearer picture.

I can only deduce that this is a deep pitted chip in the coating for a bathtub. If so this has gotten down into the steel or cast iron of the tub where the iron content has started to rust. Rust, as you may know, is a reddish brown color.

Comment: No, it's the rear side panel of a Volkswagen mini-bus.